# set style of seek bar

Tags: android, android-styles, android-seekbar

I am a noob on android graphics and I would like to change the appearance of a seek bar without creating a completely new custom view. I noticed that if I change the android:theme="@android:style/theme..." of the activity in the android manifest the style of the seek bar change. But what if I want a particular style for the seek bar only and keep unchanged the style of the activity? How can I see all possible precompiled styles?

Obviously, the question is for all other views also...

Comment: you can change theme of all views independently

Comment: @Hellboy I tried it, but if I set Holo theme for the seek bar the style doesn't change, while it change if I set Holo theme to the whole activity...

Comment: try use app:theme instead of android:thame

Comment: It doesn't work for me...

Comment: It worked with style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.SeekBar". Thanks!